# 'testdir must be an absolute path' printed after using 'ls' command in fish shell

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, fuse, fish

Every time I use the `ls` command in fish shell, it produces the line "`testdir must be an absolute path`" before then listing the contents of the directory as any normal `ls` invocation would do. This occurs regardless of the directory I am in or options I pass to `ls`.

I've scoured my system and the internet for this message, and I found it in one libfuse's test [files](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/test/test_syscalls.c#L1434). Running `ps -ef | grep fuse` produces:

```
mdko 3498 3430 0 20:36 ? 00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
```

Indeed, running `dmesg | grep fuse` shows:

```
[    3.771372] fuse init (API version 7.26)
```

When I run `ls` in bash or zsh, the message "`testdir must be an absolute path`" does not appear when running `ls`. I've also made other minimal attempts at investigating the problem by `strace`-ing the `ls` call and the `fish` process, but with no success.

Where is this string coming from, and how do I stop it?

(Running Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit, fish version 2.6.0)

Comment: Thanks to the answer below, I was able to find the problem. The `test` binary being used was in `/usr/local/bin/`, rather than `/usr/bin`, and removing the binary in `/usr/local/bin/` so that fish would use the one in `/usr/bin/` solved it. I suppose that I may have installed this extra binary when writing a filesystem with fuse several years ago, and fish is the only one that was finding it its path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fish provides an `ls` wrapper function that turns on color and indicators if the output is going to a tty (i.e. if `isatty` returns true).

Most likely, you have a command or function that overrides something here.

Check the output of `type ls` to see the definition of the `ls` function:

```
ls is a function with definition
# Defined in /usr/share/fish/functions/ls.fish @ line 6
function ls --description 'List contents of directory'
    set -l param --color=auto
    if isatty 1
        set -a param --indicator-style=classify
    end
    command ls $param $argv
end
```

Since your "ls" command works in bash, that probably isn't it (run `command ls --color=auto --indicator-style=classify somedir` to confirm).

So you'd check the other commands. `set` probably isn't it because if that was overridden you'd have bigger issues. `isatty` is possible, and that runs `command test`, which is also a candidate. Use `type` to figure out what fish is calling, and then change that.

E.g. it's possible that you have a `test` command somewhere that isn't a POSIX-style `test`, but instead a thing to run the libfuse tests. If so, rename or remove that.